# FB API send POST with image

Tags: image, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Could you tell me please how can I send a post with image by FB graph API?
I have something like this (as find in many examples)

```
// This works fine
$fb->api( '/me/feed', 'POST', ['message' => 'Whatever I want to send as a string...'] );

// But this makes me crazy
$fb->api( '/me/feed', 'POST', ['picture' => "http://xxx.yyy.zz/images/facebook_share.jpg"] );
```

This throws me an error "**(#100) A link must be provided if a picture URL is given.**"

So I tried some modification in this form

```
$fb->api( '/me/feed', 'POST', ['picture' => ['url' => "http://xxx.yyy.zz/images/facebook_share.jpg"]] );
```

But this throws me an error "**(#100) picture should represent a valid URL**" I tried to change "url" to "link", "picture_url", "source", "src" but still the same error.

I am at the end. Help me please.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So my dear colleague find out the working style is

```
$fb->api( '/me/feed', 'POST', ['picture' => "http://autostyl.frio.sk/images/facebook_share.jpg", 'link' => 'http://autostyl.frio.sk'] );
```

Thanks Facebook for your terrible documentation and stupid error messages.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tested the code in this way but this should work:

`$fb->api( '/me/photos', 'POST', ['message' => 'My message', 'source' => $fb->fileToUpload('direct/path/to/image.jpg')] );`

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookFile/5.0.0

*Don't think posting to profiles is possible anymore so you'd need to do this with a page*

`$fb->api( '/' . $page_id . '/photos', 'POST', ['message' => 'My message', 'source' => $fb->fileToUpload('direct/path/to/image.jpg')] );`

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**Uploading picture**

```
$fb->api('/me/photos', 'POST', ['url'=>"http://xxx.yyy.zz/images/facebook_share.jpg"] );
```

Make sure to have `publish_actions` permisson and to use latest version of Graph API (v2.8).

**Posting picture**

```
$fb->api('/me/feed', 'POST', ['link'=>"http://xxx.yyy.zz/images/facebook_share.jpg"] );
```

Make sure to have `user_posts` permission.

Comment: Working form is `$fb->api( '/me/feed', 'POST', ['picture' => "http://xxx.yyy.zz/images/facebook_share.jpg", 'link' => 'http://xxx.yyy.zz'] );` I dont know why but there must be the link param.

Comment: @Čamo check my answer, should help